# Firebase Realtime Database rules - How to SET data for a new user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The below rule gives access to only the owners of the account.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to maintain this level of access control but how do I permit a new user to create (SET) his `$user_id` when he logs in for the first time?

With the current rules `SET` permission is not there for `/users/`

Answer (score 1):

As long as your user writes the data under their UID,, your rules should already work. A `.write` rule covers both the case of creating the node, and updating it.

If the rule is not working for you, please edit your question to show the minimal complete/standalone code that any of us can run against these rules to reproduce the problem.